# What are the possible endings and how to get them?

Tags: secret-files-3

Various sources plus an achievement ("experience all four endings") in [Secret Files 3](http://secretfiles.deepsilver.com/en/index.php) after finishing the game state that there are four possible endings.

Which actions decide the ending?

One point might be this one, but even though it's rather late in the game I'd prefer to have a confirmation than playing it again from that point just to see the same ending as before.

> Saving Max vs not saving Max after he was poisoned. He survives in both cases but might be pissed in the latter case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four endings, depending on whether you help Cassandra and Max or not. Therefore, you can help Cass and not help Max, you can help both of them, you can help neither of them, or you can help Max but not Cassandra. I suggest you make two saves before making decisions in question and then proceed from that point on.

Comment: Luckily I did have a save from right before the Max decision